# Script to get movie posters images (from amazon ?) from a list of movies

Tags: download, language-agnostic

I would like to create a poster showing the movies I've seen, in this fashion : https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z1js.jpg

I have a text file with the list of movies, I know how to create the poster from a bunch of images (imagemagick...), what I don't know is how to download the images.

How can I automate the task of finding the movie and downloading its poster ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for the movie and screen scraping http://www.impawards.com would also be a solution, yet a bit process-intensive and a bit shady (TOS usually forbid you to). You would then enter a query, parse the results, go to the poster page and get the URL of the displayed image

Other than that, check out the (unofficial) IMDB API, http://www.imdbapi.com/ and the SPARQL endpoint at http://www.linkedmdb.org/ . You could then try to parse the IMDB page as well.

**Later edit** : Found a web service as well, looks ok, don't know about comprehensiveness / reliability or which services are used to get the links : http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/WebService-MoviePosterDB/WebService/MoviePosterDB.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Construct URLs for each movie and then use [`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) to download the images.